# How to make a page automatically redirect if a field item called "arch" is yes or checked?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

Edit: Apologies that **was** a bit broad.
The list item is named "Redacted"
It is a checkbox ( true or false ).
If it is toggled to be true then when the page is loaded or was clicked on the user is redirected to a page saying it has been redacted and that they need to contact "this person".
I don't know how to code in JQuery much at all, but would had been able to do it in VBScript. I definitely need to learn JQuery faster time permitting.

A while back in ASP Classic, I would just use some VBScript to determine if a value was true, if it was then I had the page redirect.
I am not ASP.net savvy nor a JQuery expert but how would you do this in SharePoint 2010 Designer or a CEWP?

Comment: That's a bit broad. Please edit your question and specify which DOM element you want to check and what action you want to take. What determines the value? Is it user input or some other event? We can help you with the required jQuery code but you need to provide more details.